# Cebu City not an option in weather applet

Tags: gnome, applet

I don't get it. Why does the options for cities under Philippines not include Cebu City when it is the 2nd largest city next to Manila? How do we get this included in the weather applet options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weather applet gets its information for from the [U.S. National Weather Service](http://www.weather.gov/). This service only provides data for a very limited amount of locations, in particular for non-U.S. locations like the [Philippines](http://weather.noaa.gov/weather/PH_cc.html). Even for U.S. locations coverage is not great apparently. Here is a related [Ubuntu bug report](https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-applets/+bug/403184).

There does not seem to be an alternative GNOME applet. If you do not mind installing a couple of extra packages and customizing your desktop in a bit "hackish" way, you can use the weather applet of the [XFCE project](http://www.xfce.org/) (of course, you could also directly switch to [xubuntu](http://www.xubuntu.org/) :-)): Install the packages `xfce4-panel` and `xfce4-weather-plugin` and add an XFCE panel. Then add the weather applet. This applet uses weather.com data and should be able to provide information for Cebu City.

Comment: Ahhh... indeed it is very limited. That is sad. Thanks for the answer. Can you suggest a good alternative weather applet that runs on the panel? I don't need fancy widgets on the desktop. I almost never look at the desktop. I prefer it visible directly from the panel.

Comment: The only alternative I know of is the XFCE plugin, I added some info to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The weather applet uses a library called `libgweather`. The GNOME Project [has instructions](http://live.gnome.org/LibGWeather/ImprovingLocations) on how to add your city to the data package.

Marcel Stimberg points out that there is already an [open bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=626262) in GNOME to add support for your city.

Comment: Actually there's already a bug report for Cebu: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=626262 But where does libgweather get its data from, is it capable of using other providers than the US Weather Service?

Comment: This is weird. I got curious and dug deeper. Cebu Airport is wrongly listed in /usr/share/libgweather/Locations.xml with RPVM (this is ICAO) code but instead it is under the name of Masbate which is totally another airport.  The latter's correct code is RPVJ, coordinates @ 12.366667 123.616667

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about weather applet in default Ubuntu clock? You can manually enter longitude and lattitude of your city there.

Comment: No it is the Weather Report applet I am talking about. The one that can be added to the panel. There is no option for my city which is Cebu.